# I have a select box gender and I want to change the the label of other fields after changing of this gender i

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, onchange

I have a select box gender and I want to change the the label of other fields after changing of this gender

My code is here

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-3">Gender</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <select class="form-control" id="gender" name="gender" onchange="changelabel()">
        <option value="">Gender</option>
        <option <?php if($res['gender']=='Female'){?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="Female">Female</option>
        <option <?php if($res['gender']=='Male'){?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="Male">Male</option>
    </select> 

    <!-- Other fields are -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3"><span id="prtttl">Wife Title</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <select class="form-control" id="partnerTtl" name="partnerTtl">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option <?php if($res['partnerTtl']=='Smt'){?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="Smt">Smt</option>
                        <option <?php if($res['partnerTtl']=='Late'){?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="Late">Late</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3"><span id="prtnms">Wife Name</span> </label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" name="hwname" value="<?php echo $res['partnerName'] ?>" placeholder="Husband/Wife Name" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When user select male the the label of wife name will be the same if the user select gender female the label change to husband name is this any possible way to do this with javascript

Comment: THis code is a mess jesus

Comment: Why not just use the word “spouse” to begin with - and be done with it? Added bonus - that automatically removes the possible discrimination issue (and depending on where exactly this is going to be deployed, the possible law suit to follow) you would otherwise be creating here by going with the rather outdated assumption of "marriage = one man + one woman" ...

Comment: @cbroe here here!

Comment: @Anthony hear hear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this jquery

```
function changelabel()
    {
        if($("#gender").val() == 'Female')
        {
            $("#prtttl").text("Husband's Title");
            $("#prtnms").text("Husband's Name");
        }
        else
        {
           $("#prtttl").text("Wife's Title");           
           $("#prtnms").text("Wife's Name");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great @madhukanttiwari to accept same answer but later one rather than the earlier one

Answer (score 0):

try `onchange` event like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('select').on('change', function() {
              data=this.value;
              if (data=='female') {
                $(".your class or Id").append('<span id="prtnms">Wife Name</span>');

              }
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your JS function as below:

```
<script>
function changelabel(){
  if($("#gender").val() == 'Female')
  {
     $("#prtttl").html("Husband Title");
     $("#prtnms").html("Husband Name");
  }
  else
  {
     $("#prtttl").html("Wife Title");
     $("#prtnms").html("Wife Name");    
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
function changelabel() {
   if ($('#gender').val()== 'Female') {
       $('#prtnms').text('Husband Name')
   else
       $('#prtnms').text('Wife Name');
}
```

But as you tagged jQuery, you can do this instead:

```
$("#gender").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Female') {
       $('#prtnms').text('Husband Name')
   else
       $('#prtnms').text('Wife Name');
});
```

Note that, as the content is just text, I've used `text()` instead of `html()`